# counting content with tag in foreach loop wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, random, foreach, tags

I am trying to show only tags which have more than specific number of posts. To achieve this I modified my tag-links.php code as below. But with this code I got some weird behavior. My page don't show any tag below the number of content, it is ok, but sometimes it also hides other tags. when I refresh the page it will show different tags or don't show any tags. I am newbie with php syntax, so I am not sure but code seems correct. Can you tell me the code problem, or any practical approach to solve my problem.

PS: code also include this function, every tag redirect user to random post with this specific tag, it works well.

```
<?php
    $tags      = get_the_tags( $post->ID );
    $separator = ' ';
    $output    = '';
    if ( $tags ) {
        $link = "";
        $xnumber = 0;  //number for contents with specific tag
        echo '<div class="entry-tags">';
        echo "<p><span>" . __(  ) . "</span>";
        foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
            $posts = get_posts("post_type=post&orderby=rand");
            foreach($posts as $post) {
                if(has_tag($tag->term_id)) {
                    $xnumber++;
                    if($xnumber >= 1) {
                        $link = get_permalink($post);
                        break 1;
                    } else {  }
              } else {  }
            }
            if($xnumber >= 1) {
                $output .= '<a href="' . esc_url( $link ) . '" title="' 
                        . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts tagged %s",
                        'tracks' ), $tag->name ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $tag->name ) 
                        . '</a>' . $separator;
                unset($link);
                unset($xnumber);
            } else { 
                unset($link);
                unset($xnumber);
            }               
        } 
        echo trim( $output, $separator );
        echo "</p>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
```

Comment: replace unset($xnumber); to $xnumber = 0;

Comment: sorry but it didn't help. same behavior continues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so a couple of things:

1) You arent using the get_posts function the way it's documented.  You should be passing in an array of settings.  Here's the link to documentation:  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/

2) The get_posts() function has a default limit of 5 records.  And you're bringing back the list in random order.  So, sometimes the 5 records you get will have the tag you're looking for, and sometimes it wont.  If you want it to check more records, you'll need to change the numberposts.

Following example displays posts tagged with 'jazz', under 'genre' custom taxonomy, using 'tax_query':

```
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'genre',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'jazz'
        )
    )
);
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
```

That may be more what you're looking for...

A better example using post tags:

```
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
        'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $tag
        )
    )
};
```

Comment: thanks, i will try this solution. But i want to clearly understand this function. i already get some documentation for that solution before, but it seems complicated, i didnt get well what taxonomy, field or terms stands for.

Comment: Added a second example that gives you a direct example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: i am still missing something, somehow this array doesnt populated with this query, if i set count limit to zero, tags become a visible, but if i use any number bigger than zero if statement never executed and i can't see any tag. my code implementation be like..

Comment: echo '<div class="entry-tags">';
  echo "<p><span>" . __(  ) . "</span>";
   foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
    //$posts = get_posts('numberposts=6&tag__in=' . array( $tags->term_id ));
    //
    $args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
        'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $tag
        )
    )
);
    $postslist = get_posts($args);
     
     if(count($postlist) >=1) {
      
       $specipage = $postlist[mt_rand(0, count($postlist) - 1)];

Comment: ok i can't figured out the problem with example array but i found another solution, and now it is working. it is using tax_query and my code is :  $posts = get_posts( array(
        
 'tax_query'      => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'post_tag',
                'field'     => 'slug',
                'terms'     => $tag
            )
        )
  ) );

Comment: Your solution is the same as I posted.  You would pass the $args variable to the get_posts() function.

Comment: yes it is using same approach, thanks for clarifying how tax queries work :)